# Does maven-shade-plugin work with scala classes?

Tags: scala, maven, maven-shade-plugin, scala-maven-plugin

I have a maven project with both Java and Scala components, but when I use maven-shade-plugin, it relocates package names for both Java and Scala files, but ONLY renames packages inside Java files, Scala files still contain the older package names, what am I missing?

````
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.1</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>shade</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <!--<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>-->
                           <artifactSet>
                               <includes>
                                   <include>ml.dmlc:xgboost4j-spark</include>
                                   <include>ml.dmlc:xgboost4j</include>
                               </includes>
                           </artifactSet>
                           <filters>
                               <filter>
                                   <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                   <excludes>
                                       <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                       <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                       <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                   </excludes>
                               </filter>
                           </filters>
                           <relocations>
                               <relocation>
                                   <pattern>ml.dmlc.xgboost4j</pattern>
                                   <shadedPattern>ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.shaded</shadedPattern>
                               </relocation>
                           </relocations>
                           <transformers>
                           </transformers>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>```
````

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this? @Jas Bali

Comment: Did you find solution

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, I believe that Maven is intended to have this functionality but, currently (Dec 2020), it does not.

This can be seen with this bug ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-345

**workaround**

I have personally done a silly workaround for this. I make a new empty mvn project that has the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>28.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

And the plugin:

```
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.google.</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>shader.com.google.</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then in the project with code that requires a low version of guava and a new version of guava, include the empty project as a dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yoursite.yourwork</groupId>
        <artifactId>shader</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then in a .scala file you import the new (version 28) guava classes like this:

```
import shader.com.google.common.graph.Network
```

**Why this works**

Since the error only occurs in scala projects where you refer to your own class that uses the dependency, or as said in the question **"Scala files still contain the older package names"**, shading a project that does not refer to its own dependencies bypasses the bug.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it does. Choose any [build version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin) you want and import the library into your Scala project.

Comment: I don’t have sbt because I am using maven as a build tool and using maven Scala plugin with project structure following conventions src/main/java and src/main/scala

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-shade-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I don’t think you read my question, i know how to use the plugin. I am doing all of that but package names inside scala files are not getting updated to the new shaded package names.

Comment: maven-shade plugin is supposed to relocate all package references in a jar. This doesn't answer the question why some of the relocation fails